# Javascript class methods versus properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I've seen code using Javascript classes use the following form (example is React):

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }
}
```

Why is `handleOpen` implemented as a property which is set to a function instead of something like:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  }

  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that `foo = ...` is an *experimental feature*. It isn't part of any spec yet, certainly not ES6.

Comment: @FelixKling, which part are you referring to?

Comment: @Chris: the syntax `name = value` inside the class body alongside method definitions (`foo() {}`). That's currently a proposal and not officially part of the language. See https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/ .

Comment: @FelixKling, gosh I didn't even notice. I do however think that OP just omitted the constructor to make the examples short. I labeled the question as ES6 because of the use of arrow functions.

Comment: @FelixKling I figured as much, but a lot of the React code snippets I've seen are using this syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's also a function, but it's called an **arrow function** and works slightly differently from the "traditional" implementation. It was introduced with ECMAScript 6.

Here's what the [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) says:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and does not bind its own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

---

One of the major benefits is that you wouldn't need to bind `this` to that function, because arrow functions do not have their own `this` object:

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value

This guarantees scope safety; it's impossible to use the incorrect `this` by accident. It is arguably also slightly more readable.

A drawback however would be that arrow functions are anonymous, meaning that it would be harder to do a stack trace when you get an error in your code.But for React applications we can use devtool:'cheap-module-eval-source-map' from babel to easily find bugs in our stack trace.

Comment: Another difference is that the class instance syntax (assigning the arrow function) creates a new Function for every instance of the component. With the class method syntax, there is a single Function that all instances reference and for which they set the appropriate context before calling (like a prototype chain). If you were to use the class instance syntax where it's not needed you would be creating unneeded Functions, and potentially a lot of them, at run time.

Comment: @Chris what Ross is talking about makes up a much bigger difference than whether the function is an arrow function or not – `handleOpen = () => ...` will assign a *copy* of this function for every class instance. `handleOpen () { ... }` will assign it *once* on `UserProfile.prototype`. In general, the `prototype` method should be preferred as it will not duplicate function assignments

Answer (score 1):

It's about the context of `this` inside of your method. If you would implement it like your second example, `this` won't reference the component instance, using the arrow function like in your first example `this` references the component instance. (Due to not using `React.createClass`).

For your second example you have to do `this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this)` inside your constructor.

EDIT: For details about `arrow functions` see the answer from `Chris`.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense!