# Express middleware - TypeError: Cannot write private member #nextId to an object whose class did not declare it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, middleware

I'm writing a custom logger for my express JS app and I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot write private member #nextId to an object whose class did not declare it` in my middleware function. Here is some of my code:

logger.js:

```js
const logger = new class Logger {
   // ....
   #nextId = 0;
   // ....
   setupMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        // ....
        if (!fs.existsSync(logFilename))
            this.#nextId = 0; // HERE IS THE ERROR
        // ...
        next();
   }
   // ...
}
module.exports = logger;
```

main.js:

```js
// ... requirements
server.use(logger.setupMiddleware); // this is the function!!
server.use(express.json());
server.use(delEmptyData);
server.use(queryToBody);
server.use(logger.startMiddleware);
// ... routing
server.use(exceptionHandler); // Exception handling
server.use(logger.endMiddleware);
// ... rest of the code
```

I think that somehow the middleware does not provide `this` context or something, but I don't have any idea how to solve this. (I also tried to make it all static, but I got more confusing errors)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of the `this` context as you have mentioned. There's plenty of questions / articles out there explain how to use it but I will give a brief explanation just for your case here.

The general idea is, when you use a class method by directly referring to it like: `logger.setupMiddleware`, the function is not bounded to a specific instance. In order to solve this, you can use one of the following method:

1. Manually bound it in your constructor:

```
class Logger {
  constructor() {
    this.setupMiddleware = this.setupMiddleware.bind(this);
  }
}
```

2. Make it into a class property [(More info here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423947/javascript-class-methods-versus-properties):

```
class Logger {
  setupMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  }
}
```

3. Bound it in your caller:

```
server.use(logger.setupMiddleware.bind(logger));
```

You can read more about this `Function.prototype.bind()` method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind